# Upload multiple files from dynamically created form inputs

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, mean-stack

I'm learning MEAN stack and have trubles on a files upload. I have a company form:

```
this.companyForm = this.fb.group({
      trucks: this.fb.array([]),
      ...
    });
```

Trucks field is dynamicly created:

```
newTruck(): FormGroup {
    this.added = false;
    return this.fb.group({
      ...
      TLic: new FormControl(null, {
        validators: [Validators.required]
      }),
      Lic: new FormControl(null, {
        validators: [Validators.required]
      }),
      CMRLic: new FormControl(null, {
        validators: [Validators.required]
      })
    })
  }

  addTruck() {
    this.trucks().push(this.newTruck());
  }
```

On save form:

```
this.authService.createUserStep1(
     ...
      this.companyForm.value.trucks
    );
```

AuthService:

```
createUserStep1(... trucks: Array<any>) {
    const AuthDataStep1: AuthDataStep1 = {
      ...
      trucks: trucks
    };
    this.http.put(BACKEND_URL + "signupStep1/", AuthDataStep1).subscribe(
      () => {
        this.authStatusListener.next(true);
        this.router.navigate(["auth/signupStep2"]);
      },
      error => {
        this.authStatusListener.next(false);
      }
    );
  }
```

Nodejs controller where I write to DB:

```
exports.createUserStep1 = (req, res, next) => {
    ...
        for (i = 0; i < req.body.trucks.length; i++) {
          
          const truck = new Truck({
            ...
            TLic: req.body.trucks[i].file.TLic[0].filename,
            Lic: req.body.trucks[i].file.Lic[0].filename,
            CMRLic: req.body.trucks[i].file.CMRLic[0].filename,
          });
          Truck.create(truck);
        }
      })
}
```

Middleware for files upload:

```
const multer = require("multer");
var path = require('path');

const storage = multer.diskStorage({
  destination: (req, file, cb) => {
    cb(null, "backend/truckdocs");
  },
  filename: (req, file, cb) => {
    const name = file.originalname
      .toLowerCase()
      .split(" ")
      .join("-");
    cb(null, name + "-" + Date.now() + "." + path.extname(file.originalname));
  }
});

module.exports = multer({ storage: storage }).fields([
  {
    name: "TLic", maxCount: 1
  }, {
    name: "Lic", maxCount: 1,
  }, {
    name: "CMRLic", maxCount: 1
  }
]);
```

and route

```
const express = require("express");

const UserController = require("../controllers/user");
const extractTruckFiles = require("../middleware/truckfiles");
const checkAuth = require("../middleware/check-auth");

const router = express.Router();

/*App*/
...
router.put("/signupStep1", checkAuth, extractTruckFiles, UserController.createUserStep1);
```

I want to create x number of trucks in form and for each truck upload 3 files(TLic, Lic, CMRLic).What is the best way to achieve this? I know it needs time for you to get into my code and I'm very thankful in advance.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] with focus on "minimal". I'm sure authentication and truck registration numbers are not necessary to present your problem. You can post a link to a stackblitz project.

Comment: What is the issue? I want to do X is not a question for SO.

Comment: First step, add ```multiple``` on ```file``` and itterate all the details based on the number of files you recived.

Comment: Updated! @AndrewAllen, x number of trucks

Answer (score 0):

This is how i did for a ecommerce where i upload 3 photo. I have done it with MVC pattern and i called multer in route file.

```
const express = require("express")
const multer = require("multer");

const router = express.Router()

const productController = require("../../controller/vendor/product")


const app = express();

const fileStorage = multer.diskStorage({
  destination: (req, file, cb) => {
    cb(null, "images");
  },
  filename: (req, file, cb) => {
    cb(null, new Date().toISOString().replace(/:/g, '-') + '-' +file.originalname)
  }
});

const fileFilter = (req, file, cb) => {
  if(file.mimetype === 'image/png' || file.mimetype === 'image/jpg' || file.mimetype === 'image/jpeg') {
    cb(null, true)
  } else {
    cb(null, false)
  }
}

let filehandler = app.use(multer({storage : fileStorage, fileFilter: fileFilter }).array('image',3))

/* @GET product Page request */
router.get('/products', productController.getProduct)


/* @GET add product  page Request */
router.get('/add-product', productController.getAddProduct)

/* @POST Request */
router.post('/add-product', filehandler, productController.postAddProduct)




/* @GET AJAX Request findind subcategory */
router.get("/getSubCategory/:id", productController.getSubCategory);

module.exports = router
```